# Why the horizontal scrollbar doesn't work in my grid control?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress, scrollbar

Hi I have a control which includes 3 grid controls, they are gridControl1, gridControl2 and gridControl3 and the views are gridView1, gridView2 and gridView3.

I have 3 buttons, when click Button1, gridControl1 and gridView1 display; click Button2, gridControl2 and gridView2 display; click Button3, gridControl3 and gridView3 display.

I hope there could be a horizontal scrollbar displays as well with each grid control/grid view. And hence I have below code for each gridview:

```
gridView1.OptionsView.columnAutoWidth = false;
gridView1.ScrollStyle = ScrollStyleFlags.LiveHorzScroll;
gridView1.HorzScrollVisibility = ScrollVisibility.Always; // or ScrollVisibility.Auto doesn't work neither; or remove this line, doesn't work neither
```

Then I have:

```
this.Controls.Add(this.gridControl1);
this.Controls.Add(this.gridControl2);
this.Controls.Add(this.gridControl3);
this.AutoScroll = true;
```

With `gridView1.HorzScrollVisibility = ScrollVisibility.Always` I can see the scrollbar but it is not enabled and my columns are still auto adjust the width so the total width doesn't exceed the grid width. With this `gridView1.HorzScrollVisibility` sets as other values, the horizontal scrollbar is not visible at all.

Do I need to set column min width to make this scrollbar works? Or anything I may miss and hence it doesn't work properly?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need to do is to set this to false :

```
gridView1.OptionsView.ColumnAutoWidth = false;
gridView2.OptionsView.ColumnAutoWidth = false;
gridView3.OptionsView.ColumnAutoWidth = false;
```

Comment: We have some database setting changed the ColumnAutoWidth later on, so even I set it here in designer, it doesn't work. After we change the view setting in our database, it works. Thanks for your answer!